# how to find particular phrase in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, text

I am trying to check whether a phrase of the form `$str."s[num]"`, for example `hello3his12`, where in this case `$str="hello3hi"`, exists in a string `$string`, and if it does return the value of [num] as `$num`, where in this case `$num=12`.

This is  what I tried to to check where a phrase exists in $string

```
$string ="(dont:jake3rs120 [mik])";
$str = "jake3r";
if(preg_match('~^'.$str.'s([0-9]+)$~', $string)){
    echo 'phrase exists';
}else{
    echo'phrase does not exist';
}
```

problem is this always returns false, does anyone know why?

Comment: `^` and `$` are subject start and end markers. They're not regex decoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mario says in his comment, `^` matches the start of the string, `$` the end of the string. So in your example code, `preg_match` returns `false` because there are additional characters in your string on both sides of the string you want to match:

```
(dont:jake3rs120 [mik])
```

Your code would work if the value of `$string` was `jake3rs120`.

So to make it match your example string, just remove the `^` and `$`:

```
if(preg_match('~'.$str.'s([0-9]+)~', $string)) {
    echo 'phrase exists';
} else {
    echo'phrase does not exist';
}
```

To get the number after `s`, use the third parameter of `preg_match`:

```
if(preg_match('~'.$str.'s([0-9]+)~', $string, $matches)) {
    echo 'phrase exists';
    echo $matches[1]; // Echoes the number after s.
} else {
    echo'phrase does not exist';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Is it possible to get the number after `s` if phrase exists?